# Transmit and receive 16 bit data register Slave and 8 bit register master AVR Via SPI communication

Tags: microcontroller, avr, atmega, atmelstudio

I'm beginner with Avr programming, I have a 16 bit register slave (memory chip), and I want to read and write in the memory  via Atmega328 (8 bit register ), I know that I have to send 8 by 8 bit, I already tried to program this but I was no able to read from my slave with the Atmel Studio debugger, can anyone can advice me please ?

The protocol of communication with my chip is the SPI.

Serial communication is discribed in the datasheet of the Chip as :

1. READ :

To read from the chipi have to send:

```
0x03            = 0b00000011:          8 bit  READ command
0x0000 - 0x07FF = 0bXXXXXAAA AAAAAAAA: 16 bit ADDRESS (5 upper bits don't care)
```

Then i will receive:

```
0x0000 - 0xFFFF = 0bDDDDDDDD DDDDDDDD: 16 bit DATA
```

2. WRITE :

To write to the chip i have to send:

```
0x02            = 0b00000010:          8 bit  WRITE command
0x0000 - 0x07FF = 0bXXXXXAAA AAAAAAAA: 16 bit ADDRESS (5 upper bits don't care)
0x0000 - 0xFFFF = 0bDDDDDDDD DDDDDDDD: 16 bit DATA
```

3. Memory layout:

The user memory area goes from 0x0000 to 0xA6F.

4. Use the SPI information register:

In the Serial communication mode, if the LSI encount ers an error when executing a READ/WRITE command, the error codes will be stored in the e SPI Error Information Register.

```
Bit       15 14 13 12 11 10 9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
Function  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  | ERROR* |
* :  ERROR
b1000 : Low voltage detection
b0100 : Write NG
b0010 : Read NG
b0001 : NG because RF occurred
b0000 : Finished successfully
```

My SPI init is:

```
void spi_init()
// Initialize pins for spi communication
{

    // set MOSI , select chip SS and SCK Output, all others are outputs
    DDR_SPI |= ((1<<DD_MOSI)|(1<<DD_SCK) );/*|(1<<DD_SS))*/
    // set MISO us input 

     //Enable SPI, Master, set clock rate
     SPCR = (1<<SPE|(1<<MSTR)| (1<<SPR0)|       // SPI Enable
    (0<<SPIE)|              // SPI Interrupt Enable
    (0<<DORD)|              // Data Order (0:MSB first / 1:LSB first)
    (1<<MSTR)|              // Master/Slave select
    (0<<SPR1)|(1<<SPR0)|    // SPI Clock Rate
    (1<<CPOL)|              // Clock Polarity (0:SCK low / 1:SCK hi when idle)
    (1<<CPHA));           // Clock Phase (0:leading / 1:trailing edge sampling)

    SPSR = (1<<SPI2X);              // Double Clock Rate

}

void SPI_MasterTransmit(uint16_t cdata){
    SPDR = cdata;  //start transmission 
    while(!(SPSR & (1<<SPIF)));  // wait for transmission complete
}
 uint16_t SPI_SlaveReceive(void){
     while(!(SPSR & (1<<SPIF)));  //wait for reception complete     
     return (SPDR);             //return Data Register
 }
```

**Read:**

```
uint16_t read_SPI( uint16_t address){
    uint16_t datar; 
        Slave_select;   
    // charger les données inf au buffer 
        SPDR = uint16_t( address & 0xFF);
        //attente lors de la premiere transmission 
        while(!(SPSR & (1<<SPIF) ));
        // premier octet est reçu 
        datar = SPDR;

        // charger les données sup au buffer 
        SPDR = uint16_t ((address >> 8) & 0xFF);
        //attente de la seconde tr 
        while(!(SPSR & (1<<SPIF) ));
        // seceond octet est reçu 
        datar = datar | ((uint16_t) (SPDR) << 8);
       Slave_deselect;
        return datar; 

}
```

**Write**

```
void write_SPI (uint16_t address, uint16_t data){
    Slave_select;
    SPDR= data; 
    while(!(SPSR & (1<<SPIF)));
    /*data = SPDR;*/ // erase SPDR register 
    Slave_deselect; 
}
```

Comment: Have you looked with the scope at what's coming out of the SPI port? Can we see your init code and the code you're using to access the flash? We need way more info than this.

Comment: No i just looked to the debugger

Comment: @DiBosco i posted my Code as answer to my question

Comment: One thing that immediately springs to mind is you've not unlocked the flash. Check the datasheet how to do that. Also, you really need to look at your SPI lines with a scope to ensure they are doing what you think they are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You never actually send the command and only the lower 8 bits of the address.

Roughly, on the ATmega-side pin setup should look like this:

```
PORT? = (1u << MISO) | (1u << MOSI) | (1u << SCK) | (1u << CS);
DDR? = (1u << MOSI) | (1u << CS) | (1u << SCK);
/* pull-up on MISO, init all others idle high/active low */
```

Then the read function is something like this:

```
uint16_t read_SPI( uint16_t address){
    uint16_t res;
    PORT? &= ~(1u << CS); /* assert #CS */
    SPDR = 0x03u; /* READ command */
    while(!(SPSR & (1<<SPIF) ));
    SPDR = (address >> 8) & 0xFFu; /* high-order address bits */
    while(!(SPSR & (1<<SPIF) ));
    SPDR = (address >> 0) & 0xFFu; /* low-order address bits */
    while(!(SPSR & (1<<SPIF) ));
    SPDR = 0xFFu; /* dummy write to clock in high-order data bits */
    while(!(SPSR & (1<<SPIF) ));
    res = SPDR;
    SPDR = 0xFFu; /* dummy write to clock in low-order data bits */
    res <<= 8;
    res = SPDR;
    PORT? |= (1u << CS); /* deassert #CS */
    return res;
}
```

Notice how this is a very basic example and usually you would not want to block the microcontroller indefinitely waiting for SPI status flags. However, consider getting this code to the point where you can reliably read and write to/from the EEPROM. Then you can add a bit of abstraction and use datastructures and an interrupt-based SPI routine to handle accessing the memory.